# Repeating end of the month events on iPhone Calendar, problem for February

Tags: iphone, events, calendar, repeat

This is more of an usability problem/bug/question.

I wanted to add an event to occur on the end of the month for every month.
But if I choose October 31 and set Repeat Event -> Every Month, all months ending in 30 are left out (including 28-feb).
So, I could solve this by putting the end of the month at 30, and only miss out on February... But I need it to be on the 31, when the month ends in 31;  30 when it ends in 30;  and 28 or 29 for February.

The Calendar app doesn't detect that I want it "Every Month at the end of the month".
I can't create an event for 30 and another for 31 because I would have the same event twice on months ending in 31.

So, anyone have a way around this?

Of course, going to each month and setting it is not an answer I'm looking for. And requesting 28-day 13-month calendars isn't either.

Comment: I think you're pretty much out of luck. Adding 12 events (one per month) is probably the closest you can get, and you already rejected that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the graphic calendar solution aside, and try something like:

> Repeat event <*Monthly*> on <*first*> <*Friday*>
>   Repeat event <*Monthly*> on <*last*> <*day*>

Translate that to a programmatic schedule as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am frustrated by the same issue. Although it is not a programming solution, you could solve it by setting the calendar item for the 1st of the month and set a reminder to popup on the day before the event.